# How to use Progress Bar in Windows form

Tags: progress-bar, statusbar

I need to to use a progress bar to show the work done status in c# using asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Delete" + ProcessRows, "<script language='javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {UpdateBar(" + ProcessRows + "," + Employee.Rows.Count + ",'"+row["Name"].ToString()+"' ,'"+ row["Designation"].ToString() + "','" + row["DepartmentName"].ToString() + "');});</script>");
```

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Delete" + ProcessRows, "<script language='javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {UpdateBar(" + ProcessRows + "," + Employee.Rows.Count + ",'"+row["Name"].ToString()+"' ,'"+ row["Designation"].ToString() + "','" + row["DepartmentName"].ToString() + "');});</script>");